# python: can I extend the upper bound of the range() method?

Tags: python, python-2.x

What is the upper bound of the range() function and how can I extend it, or alternately what's the best way to do this:

```
for i in range(1,600851475143):
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`range(1, 600851475143)` wants to generate a very large list in memory, and you'll get an out of memory error. To save memory, use `xrange` instead of `range`. Unfortunately, `xrange` doesn't work with large numbers (it's an implementation restriction) Example (raises OverflowError):

```
for i in xrange(1, 600851475143):
  print i
```

You can have large minimum or maximum values in your interval with `range`, if their difference is small. Example:

```
x = 1 << 200
print list(xrange(x, x + 3))
```

Output:

```
[1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376L, 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301377L, 1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301378L]
```

A fancy solution to your original *for* loop problem:

```
def bigrange(a, b = None):
  if b is None:
    b = a
    a = 0
  while a < b:
    yield a
    a += 1

for i in bigrange(1, 600851475143):
  print i
```

A less fancy solution, which works even if you have `continue` in the loop body:

```
i = 1 - 1
while i < 600851475143 - 1:
  i += 1
  print i
```

Comment: Do you know why you would use range() instead of xrange()? xrange() is faster and more memory-efficient.

Comment: @coonj: this articles says that in some benchmarks range() was actually 1% faster. Also, xrange() has been removed in Python 3, I think.

Comment: @coonj Sometimes you actually want a list of numbers rather than an iterator over those numbers. For example, deck = range(52); random.shuffle(deck); hand = deck[:5]

On the other hand, using range when all you really want is an iterator over the numbers 1..n is really wasteful and that is where xrange comes in.

Comment: @Bastien Actually range has been removed and xrange renamed range.  If you really want a list you can just write deck = list(range(52)), but it encourages you to use the iterator unless you actually need the list.

Comment: running the above example, I get an overflow error on Python 2.6.1

Comment: Updated by answer how to avoid the OverflowError.

Answer (score 2):

pts' answer led me to this in the xrange python docs:

> Note
>
> xrange() is intended to be simple and
>   fast. Implementations may impose
>   restrictions to achieve this. The C
>   implementation of Python restricts all
>   arguments to native C longs (“short”
>   Python integers), and also requires
>   that the number of elements fit in a
>   native C long. If a larger range is
>   needed, an alternate version can be
>   crafted using the itertools module:
>   `islice(count(start, step), (stop-start+step-1)//step)`

looks like it's a limitation of c python in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just doing this?    Or is there some reason you specifically need `range()`?

```
x = 1
while x < 600851475143:
    // some code
    x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version of Python you're using.  I'm using 2.5.2 and xrange raises an OverflowError exception for large numbers.  One solution is to write your own generator.

```
def g(start, stop):
    i = start
    while i < stop:
        yield i
        i += 1

x = 1<<200
for i in g(x, x+3):
    print i
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer using [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html).  It's a little contrived, but it works:

```
from itertools import repeat, count, izip
for i,_ in izip(count(1), repeat(1, 600851475143)):
    ...
```

Another answer would be to write your own generator:

```
def my_xrange(a, b):
    while a < b:
        yield a
        a += 1

for i in my_xrange(1, 600851475143):
    ...
```